# Show that if $M$ is projective then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,.)$ is an exact functor.

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-module, hom-functor

Is there any reference that contains this proof:

Show that if $M$ is projective then $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,.)$ is an exact functor.

Or any help in the proof will be appreciated.

We defined projective module as follows:

An $R$-module $P$ is projective if, whenever $A,B$ are $R$-modules, $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(P,B),$ and $g \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(A,B),$ is surjective, there exists $\tilde{f} \in \operatorname{Hom}(P,A)$ such that $f = g \tilde{f}.$

And I proved that the $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, -)$ functor is a left exact functor. Also, I have proved if $P$ is free then $P$ is projective.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I already solved this problem:

$(a)$ Let $P$ be an $R$-module. Show that the following three conditions are equivalent.\
1.$P$ is projective.\
2. Any surjective homomorphism $g: A \rightarrow P$ of $R$-modules has a section.\
3. $P$ is a direct summand of a free module, i.e.,there is a free $R$-module $F$ and submodule $Q$ such that $F = P \oplus_R Q.$\

$(b)$ Part $(a)$ shows that, if $P$ is free, then $P$ is projective. Give an example of a finitely generated projective module which is not free.\

Comment: I think it answers some parts of my question but not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projectivity is basically defined to be exactly right exactness of $\hom_R(M,-)$; suppose we have a short exact sequence

$$0\to A\to B\overset g\to C\to 0.$$

Now you want to know that

$$0\to\hom_R(M,A)\to\hom_R(M,B)\to\hom_R(M,C)\to0$$

is right exact (you've already checked left exactness). So we really just need surjectivity of $\hom_R(M,B)\to\hom_R(M,C)$. If you have an element $f\in\hom_R(M,C)$, then by projectivity of $M$ you know there exists some $\tilde f\in\hom_R(M,B)$ such that $f=g\tilde f$. Unraveling the definitions check this is really just saying that $\tilde f\mapsto f$ under $\hom_R(M,B)\to\hom_R(M,C)$.

Comment: I think I already proved this surjectivity before, as I proved that every projective module has a section does that finish the forward direction?

Comment: I will edit my question with the problem I already solved  so that we can be on the same page.

Comment: @MathFear yes that finishes the forward direction because that proves $\hom(M,-)$ is exact.

Comment: So why having a section makes my functor right exact can you show me the diagrams?

Comment: what is your definition of right exact?

Comment: I need to show that the function on the right (third arrow of the hom sequence)is surjective and ker = im at hom(M,B) ... is that correct?

Comment: If you proved left exactness you just need to check the right is surjective, and that's exactly what I proved in my answer

Comment: I think I see your point now. what about the reverse direction? if hom exact then we have a projective module?

Comment: If hom is exact then for a surjection $A\to B$ let $K$ be the kernel and then you have an exact sequence $$0\to K\to A \to B\to0$$ then apply $\hom_R(M,-)$ and get an exact sequence; check that the surjectivity of $\hom_R(M,A)\to\hom_R(M,B)$ is exactly the property you want for $M$ to be projective.

Comment: why this surjectivity is exactly what I want, I can not see this. could u clarify please using my definition of projectivity given in the main question?

Comment: I am using your definition of projectivity. If $g:A\to B$ is the surjection you have in the definition, then you are taking the exact sequence I made and you have that $\hom_R(M,A)\to\hom_R(M,B)$ is surjective. That means if $f\in\hom_R(M,B)$ then there exists $\tilde f\in\hom_R(M,A)$ such that $\tilde f\mapsto f$. This exactly means by definition of the map $\hom_R(M,A)\to\hom_R(M,B)$ that $g\tilde f=f$.

Comment: I think I got your idea .... but that is the whole details of the solution of this direction or are their some details I should work?

Comment: I am really grateful to your patience and keen help